# Why is selenium not able to find element with ID, even when it is not in an iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to make an automatic program for logging in to GitHub. I could find only the sign-in option. After that, I could not find the Username field. I have confirmed that the element is definitely not in a/an (i)frame. I have tried an alternative with css-selector.

Here is the code I tried:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_opt = Options()
chrome_opt.add_experimental_option("detach", True)  # type: ignore[unknown]

auto = Chrome(options=chrome_opt)
auto.get("https://github.com")

signin_link = auto.find_element("link text", "Sign in")
signin_link.click()

username = auto.find_element("id", "login_field")
username.send_keys("ArnabRollin")  # type: ignore[unknown]

# FIXME
```

The type-ignore comments are there because of 'strict mode' type checking in VS Code. Also, after 5 tries of running it, it finally worked, but when I ran it again it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now your code is looking for elements in the page `https://github.com` - the one used in method `get()`

instead of clicking element's link, get it with webdriver:

```
signin_link = auto.find_element("link text", "Sign in")
signin_link.click()
```

use

```
signin_link = auto.find_element("link text", "Sign in").get_attribute('href')
auto.get(signin_link)
```

`auto.get(url2)` will save new page context into driver. after sign in is complete, a new page context will be needed

Answer (score 0):

*Note, I'm not sure it's ethical scraping this website, and besides, they have Captcha*.

You can use this CSS selector:

```
username = auto.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.js-login-field")
```

Additionally, when you go to `github.com` and click on `login`, the URL changes to `/login`: `https://github.com/login`

Comment: `I'm not sure it's ethical scraping this website, and besides, they have Captcha.`
I was following a course and the tutor was not answering. So, I'm not actually automating it...